# How do I get the decimal length to 6 decimal places in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, decimal, tofixed

I am writing code to round to six decimal places after some arithmetic. I am looping through the contents of an array and finding out the contents of the array. Then I divide it by the array length. I found the function toFixed. I am setting toFixed(6). So for example. arraycontents/array.length.toFixed(6) Should get six places after the decimal. I am only getting 1?

```js
array = [1, 1, 0, -1, -1];

var positive_count = 0;
var negative_count = 0;
var zero_count = 0;

function plusMinus(array) {

  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {


    if(array[i] > 0) {

      positive_count++;
      //console.log("Positive Count " + positive_count);
    
      
    } else if (array[i] < 0) {

      negative_count++;
      //console.log("Negative Count " + negative_count);
    } else if (array[i] == 0) {

      zero_count++;
     // console.log("Zero count " + zero_count);
    }
      
  }

  var calculatePos = positive_count/array.length.toFixed(6);
  calculatePos.toFixed(6);
  console.log(calculatePos);
  
  var calculateNeg = negative_count/array.length.toFixed(6);
  console.log(calculateNeg);
  
  var calculateZero = zero_count/array.length.toFixed(6);
  console.log(calculateZero);

  
}

plusMinus(array);
```

Comment: `toFixed()` doesn't modify the value in place, you need to assign the result. `calculatePos = calculatePos.toFixed(6);`

Comment: Thank you sir. I think this is another question of mine you have answered. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Let me quickly explain what is happening in your code logic:

```
array.length // 5
positive_count = 2;
negative_count = 2;
zero_count = 1;

var calculatePos = positive_count/array.length.toFixed(6); //    2 / 5.toFixed(6) the result should be an error.

var calculateNeg = negative_count/array.length.toFixed(6); //    2 / 5.toFixed(6) the result should be an error.
  
var calculateZero = zero_count/array.length.toFixed(6);  //      0 / 1.toFixed(6)  the result should be an error.
```

What you should do:

```
var calculatePos = (positive_count/array.length).toFixed(6); // => '0.400000' string

var calculateNeg = (negative_count/array.length).toFixed(6); // => '0.400000' string
  
var calculateZero = (zero_count/array.length.toFixed(6);  //    => '0.000000' string
```

If you wish to convert the types to a number, you can do it with `parseFloat(string)`.